# confused by UseReducer

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

Hey everybody I wonder if someone would be able to help me understand useReducer. It was suggested to me by someone because I am using a form with lots of inputs which I would like to dynamically other areas of the app. I'm new to react and i'm struggling to get it to work as I would like. Here is what I am working with so far.

```
    const Form= () => {
const useReducerState = (initialState = {
    
}) => {    
    const reducer = (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, ...next });
    return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
};

const [state, setState] = useReducerState({
input1: "",
input2: "",
input 3: "",
input 4: "",
input 6: "",
input 7: "",
input 8: "",
input 9: "",
 });


 const handleChange = (e) => {        
    let proToUpdate = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    setState({ [proToUpdate]: value });    
     }

const {
    input 1,
    input 2,
    input 3,
    input 4,
    input 5, 
    input 6,
    input 7,
    input 8,
    input 9
    
} = state;



return ( jsx form with inputs matching the state above ) }
```

The guide I followed seems to have formatted it differently to how it's done on other guides. As I don't really understand what's going on I'm unable to reset the form to the default values, which seems to be the main point of reducer. Teach me to try and cheat and just copy someone else's homework I guess :)

Comment: To be more precise, why is the initial state at the bottom in the const{} rather that at the top within the initialState = {}.

Answer (score 0):

Your post clearly reflects a lack of understanding of how React and hooks work. Please, before following any confusing guide on the internet, read the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). You can't go wrong with the official documentation as it demonstrates how it's intended to be used in the first place.

Firstly, for your code to work, you would have to move the `useReducerState` out of the component. Why? Everytime the component is rendered, `useReducerState` will be a new function. Your function is a hook, you'd be better off moving that into its own file and exporting it.

Secondly, if you know Redux, see useReducer as a local store to your component. The first argument of useReducer is a reducer and a reducer is a pure function passing the state as the first parameter and an **action** as the second parameter and returning a new state. So, I don't understand this line at all:

```
const reducer = (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, ...next });
```

"next" should be an action, that is an object with two properties: **type** (the type of action being dispatched) and **payload** (well, the payload).

This line is even more confusing:

```
const [state, setState] = useReducerState({
```

whereas `useReducer`'s signature looks like this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init);
```

So how you end up with `setState` is a mystery to me.

And lastly, I haven't seen any dispatch in your component (?) Why use a `useReducer` at all, then? Judging by your code, it looks like you wanted to use a `useState` which does return a setState in the array.

> As I don't really understand what's going on I'm unable to reset the form to the default values, which seems to be the main point of reducer.

Unclear what you mean here but the point of a reducer is to dispatch an action that will dictate what to change in your state and return the new state. With `useReducer`, you won't have to do this:

```
setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  [proPToUpdate]: value
}))
```

---

An extract from the official documentation:

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

In your case, something along these lines:

```
const initialState = {
input1: "",
input2: "",
input 3: "",
input 4: "",
input 6: "",
input 7: "",
input 8: "",
input 9: "",
 }

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setInput1':
      return { ...state, input1: action.payload};
    case 'setInput2':
      return { ...state, input2: action.payload};
    case 'reset':
      return initialState;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}


...
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
...
dispatch({ type: 'reset' });
dispatch({ type: 'setInput1', payload: value });
```

---

More on it. Yes, this code

```
const reducer = (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, ...next });
return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

did work but you lose readability. Let's call a spade a spade. When using a reducer, you have to pass an action to it. And an action has to have a type. The code above works but it's wrong. It's diverting `useReducer` from its legitimate use to get, what? less code? Yes, but never at the expense of readability and semantics. It's the same as using `.map` instead of `.forEach` when you intended to use `.forEach`.

If I see this somewhere (written by someone else):

```
setState({ [proToUpdate]: value });
```

What do you think I'd do? I'd say, hey, your code is wrong, it's supposed to be

```
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [proToUpdate]: value }));
```

and fix it. Without kwowing that there is a useReducer at play behind the scenes... It's just wrong.

I've seen plenty of people doing weird things to bargain a few lines of code and it's not always pretty, often from guides on the internet, on Medium, etc.! Don't forget that you might not be alone working on this code. Make it readable and more importantly, meaningful, for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for that. Yes, I looked at all the documentation. The reason I went to youtube was all explanations insistence on using a counter as the example. I have multiple state values I'm trying to manage and all of the examples using just one {counter} which  meant it was difficult to understand how to expand it in a real case.

Comment: I see. Do you want me to add an example?

Comment: If you could that would be fantastic. There seems to be a lack of explanations which handle multiple state values. I used reducer because I have quite a few inputs. The plan was to have one function that effectively setStates of each of the values, allowed for me to reset all of the values to a default if needed. All of the examples use one value and two types counter, decrement and increment which is confusing. What's odd about the version I found is it works. It takes the value from the input and updates state. From what you have said it's just done in a weird way. :)

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. If you now have to do a switch statement for each input what's the point. It's easier to just do a switch statement for each SetState.

Comment: The point is to factorize code! First, you won‘t have to destructure anything each time you call dispatch. And second, imagine that you have to set four different properties for a specific action. Do you want to repeat that each time or just call dispatch with the specific type and let the reducer do the job for you? Plus setting manually is prone to error. The switch is used just once, that already is an improvement. If after all that, you still don‘t see the point as you say, then use useState and stick with it. But don‘t jump through hoops to achieve the same thing as useState :)

Comment: It is even more of an improvement when you have nested objects. Because, each time you call setState, you will have to destructure all nested parents. With a reducer, it‘s done in one place only.

Comment: Okay, where does the value come from in your example.  dispatch({ type: 'setInput1', payload: value });

<select name="make" className="hardwear w-40" id="make"  required onChange={(e) => dispatch({type: 'setMake', payload: e.target.value})}>

says it's undefined

Comment: If you look at the example I provided, I wrote action.payload not value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240357/discussion-between-mark-scholes-and-jperl).